# How to use MDX custom elements in contentlayer

Tags: next.js, remarkjs, contentlayer, rehypejs

I'm building a site that makes use of Nextjs and Contentlayer to render a bunch of MDX files.

I basically followed [this tutorial](https://www.contentlayer.dev/docs/getting-started) to get it set up, except I'm going with MDX instead of plain markdown.

I'm using Contentlayer because [the standard way of supporting MDX in Next](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/using-mdx) just doesn't fit my use-case very well.

The Next.js MDX docs have a section on [Custom elements](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/using-mdx#custom-elements). It lets you, for example, decide that all your `h1`s will be rendered with your custom  component or whatever.

**My question is: Is there a way to set up custom elements when using Contentlayer?**

I assume there is some way to configure rehype or remark, I'm new to both of these tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out :)

The [contentlayer docs](https://www.contentlayer.dev/docs/sources/files/mdx#usage-from-nextjs) have a minimal example. I reproduced it here for convenience

```
const Page: React.FC<{ post }> = ({ post }) => {
  const MDXContent = useMDXComponent(post.body.code)
  
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Some code ... */}
      <MDXContent components={{ MyButton }} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you wanted to get MDX to make use of your components for all the things then you could do something like this:

```
const components = {
  p: MyTextComponent,
  h1: MyHeading1,
  h2: MyHeading2.
  ...

const Page: React.FC<{ post }> = ({ post }) => {
  const MDXContent = useMDXComponent(post.body.code)
  
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Some code ... */}
      <MDXContent components={ components } />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I wanted to replace basically every standard HTML component with a custom component. I found [this example](https://github.com/VdustR/example-material-ui-mdx/blob/master/src/components.js) useful in seeing what to include in my `components` data structure.